# SQL Server LEAD Equivalent Function in MS Access 2016

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I am trying to create some sort of Validity (Date Range) fields on my MS ACCESS table. It will need to be group by ID, Subject and Level to derive the effective period of each record. If there is no corresponding test taken to improve the grade, the effective to date will be set to 31/12/9999.

I have the following table now:

```
ID  | Subject | Level | FromGrade | ToGrade | TestDate
101 | Math    |  5    | C+        | D       | 31/11/2016
101 | Math    |  4    | D         | A       | 01/12/2016
101 | Math    |  5    | D         | B+      | 12/12/2016
101 | Math    |  5    | B+        | A       | 25/12/2016
102 | English |  4    | B         | B       | 20/12/2016
102 | English |  4    | B         | C       | 28/12/2016
```

The end resulting table i should be getting the following:

```
ID  | Subject | Level | FromGrade | ToGrade | TestDate   | EffectiveTo
101 | Math    |  5    | C+        | D       | 31/11/2016 | 11/12/2016
101 | Math    |  4    | D         | A       | 01/12/2016 | 31/12/9999
101 | Math    |  5    | D         | B+      | 12/12/2016 | 24/12/2016
101 | Math    |  5    | B+        | A       | 25/12/2016 | 31/12/9999
102 | English |  4    | B         | B       | 20/12/2016 | 27/12/2016
102 | English |  4    | B         | C       | 28/12/2016 | 31/12/9999
```

To do this in SQL Server, i could easily use the `LEAD OVER` function:

```
SELECT [ID]
, [Subject]
, [Level]
, [FromGrade]
, [ToGrade]
, [TestDate]
, [EffectiveTo] = LEAD([TestDate], 1) OVER ( PARTITION BY [ID], [Subject], [Level]  ORDER BY [TestDate] )
into StudentTable2
FROM [dbo].[StudentTable1]
ORDER BY [ID], [Subject], [Level], [TestDate]
```

and then follow by a

```
update [dbo].StudentTable2set [EffectiveTo] = DATEADD("DAY", -1, [EffectiveTo]) where EffectiveTo is not null
```

However, this is not working on Ms Access/VBA script, is there any other way i can achieve the same results?

Comment: Why not keep exact SQL Server query using an MS Access pass-thru query? Also, there is no VBA here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery.  To get the next value in MS Access:

```
SELECT st.*,
       (SELECT MIN(st2.TestDate)
        FROM dbo.StudentTable1 as st2
        WHERE st2.ID = st.ID AND
              st2.Subject = st.Subject AND
              st2.[Level] = st.[Level] AND
              st2.TestDate > st.TestDate
       ) as EffectiveTo
FROM dbo.StudentTable1 as st
ORDER BY [ID], [Subject], [Level], [TestDate];
```

Comment: this returns an error "you have written a subquery that can return more than one field without using the EXISTS reserved word in the main query's FROM clause. Revise the SELECT statement of the subquery to request only one field. "

Comment: @user1688194 . . . Oops, that should have been `MIN(TestDate)`.

Comment: now the query is returning the error code "Your query does not include the specified expression 'TestDate' as part of an aggregate function.

Comment: @user1688194 j. . . But it is the argument to `MIN()`.

Comment: That is a strange error unless OP is not running query as you posted. Do note `Level` is a [reserved word](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe) in Access which can cause funky errors. Try escaping with square brackets.

Comment: @Parfait . . . The reserved word might be the problem.